# why am I getting error: Mach-O 64-bit format does not support 32-bit absolute addresses

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, mach-o

```
    %include "along64.inc"
            default rel

    section .data

        EnterMsg    : db "Enter a number to add to the list; enter 0 when you done" ,0ah,0
        ExitMsg     : db "The sorted list: "                                        ,0ah,0
        InputError1 : db "Input Error; Integers Only"                               ,0ah,0
        InputError2 : db "Input Error; Maximum list is 100"                         ,0ah,0
        InputError3 : db "Input Error; Enter AT LEAST ONE Int"                      ,0ah,0

    segment .bss
        a:   resq   100                            ;creates a new array with 100 values set to 0

    section .text

    global main

    main:

        mov         rbx,0
        mov         rcx,0                           ;sets counter to 0
        mov         rdx, EnterMsg                    ;moves EnterMsg to rdx to be called by WriteString
        call        WriteString                      ;prints EnterMsg
        jmp         read                             ;calls readInput label

    read:                                                ;reads the input

        call        ReadInt                          ;reads integer
        jo          invalidInput                     ;jumps if not an integer value
        cmp         rcx, 100                         ;compares rcx and 100
        jg          tooManyInts                      ;if rcx is already 100, then cannot add int to array, so jump to error
        cmp         rax,0                            ;tests for the 0 input
        je          Loop1                            ;jumps to Loop1 if zero
        mov         [a +(rcx*4)], rax                ;adds read integer to array
        inc         rcx                              ;increments counter
        jmp         read                             ;loops if input is not 0

    Loop1:

        cmp         rcx, 2                           ;compares rcx to 2
        jmp         badInput                         ;jumps to badinput if less than 2
        push        rcx                              ;pushes rcx for number of numbers to print
        dec         rcx                              ;decrements rcx because 0-based indexing


Loop2:

        push        rcx                              ;saves outer loop count
        mov         rbx, 0                           ;sets rbx to 0 because 0 based indexing

Loop3:

        mov         rax,qword[a +(rbx * 4)]              ;moves current value of array, as determined by value of 
                                                     ;rbx*4, to rax
        cmp         [a + (rbx * 4) + 4], rax         ;compares next value of array with rax
        jg          Loop4                            ;if greater, jumps to L4
        xchg        rax,qword[a + (rbx*4)+4]              ;if less, exchanges values
        mov        qword[a + (rbx * 4)], rax             ;and moves new value of rax to the current value of the array

Loop4:

        inc         rbx                              ;increments rbx to iterate through array
        loop        Loop3                            ;inner loop iterates through array values once

        pop         rcx                              ;pops rcx that was previously pushed to reset count for outer loop
        loop        Loop2                            ;loops back to L2 to iterate through all values of array again


    SetWrite:
        mov         rbx, 0                           ;resets rbx to 0
        pop         rcx                              ;pops intial count for rcx, to determine how many times 
                                                     ;writeint should be called

        call        Crlf                             ;prints new line
        mov         rdx, ExitMsg                     ;moves ExitMsg to rdx
        call        WriteString                      ;writes ExitMsg

WriteArray:

        mov         [a + rcx],rax                    ;moves values of array to rax, where WriteInt calls from
        call        WriteInt                         ;writes current value of rax
        call        Crlf                             ;prints new line
        add         rbx, 4                           ;increments rbx by 4
        loop        WriteArray                       ;loops rcx times
        jmp         exit                             ;jumps to exit

WriteArrayOne:

        call        Crlf                             ;prints new line
        mov         rdx, ExitMsg                     ;moves ExitMsg to rdx
        call        WriteString                      ;writes ExitMsg

        mov         qword[a +rbx],rax                    ;moves first value of array to rax, where WriteInt calls from
        call        WriteInt                         ;writes value of rax
        call        Crlf                             ;prints new line
        jmp         exit                             ;jumps to exit

invalidInput:                                        ;jumps here if input is not an integer

        mov         rdx,InputError1                  ;moves InputError1 to rdx
        call        WriteString                      ;prints InputError1
        jmp         exit                             ;exits

tooManyInts:

        mov         rdx, InputError2                 ;moves InputError2 to rdx
        call        WriteString                      ;writes InputError2
        jmp         exit                             ;exits

badInput:

        cmp         rcx, 1                           ;if rcx == 1, prints that one value
        jmp         WriteArrayOne                    ;jumps to WriteOne which writes first int in the array

        mov         rdx, InputError3                 ;if zero, moves InputError3 to rdx
        call        WriteString                      ;writes InputError3
        jmp         exit                             ;exits

  exit:                                                ;exits program
        int         80h
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `[a+rbx*4]` and similar all assemble to absolute addressing with 32 bit displacement. You should load the address into a register first, then apply the indexing. For example:

```
lea rdx, [a]
mov [rdx + rcx*8], rax
```

Note that a `qword` is 8 bytes, so you should scale by that, or, if you have 4 byte integers you need to change to 32 bit register.

Comment: Enter a number to add to the list; enter 0 when you done
6
1
8
3
4
9
0

The sorted list: 
+0 ;this is what I m getting after edit

Comment: Well, that's a different problem. Run your code in a debugger and see where it goes wrong.

Comment: For future readers: you need `default rel` for `lea rdx, [a]` to use a RIP-relative addressing mode.  Or `lea rdx, [rel a]`, but normally just use `default rel`.